# How to read the value of a Record in typescript (the right way)

Tags: typescript

I have the following two types

```js
type SortOption = string | Record<string, "desc" | "asc">
type Item = { name: string, value: SortOption}
```

Now I have a some items:

```js
const item: Item = {
  name: "myItem",
  value: {
    version: "desc"
  }
}
```

and I try to read the the value of `version` in `value` object

```
console.log(item.value.version) // prints "desc" but shows error
```

but I'm getting the error:

```
Property 'version' does not exist on type 'SortOption'.
  Property 'version' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)
```

In the console I can actually see that the value `desc` is printed out but I get this error in vs code. I could avoid this error by casting the `SortOption` object to any

```js
console.log((item.value as any).version) // prints "desc" but doesn't show error
```

but this looks like a dirty hack and I would like to know how I can solve this in a proper way.

Comment: It's not the `Record` that's the issue; it's the `string`.  The compiler has no idea that `item.value` is not a `string` because you annotated `item` as `Item`.  Either don't annotate `item` (meaning that you and the compiler know at compile time that `item.value` is an object) or check `item.value` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N91njN) (because maybe it will actually be a string).  Which approach is appropriate for you?  What is the use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined `SortOption` as this type:

```
type SortOption = string | Record<string, "desc" | "asc">
```

That means that `item.value` might be a `string` or it might be a `Record<string, 'desc' | 'asc'>`.

For instance, this is also a valid `Item`:

```
const item: Item = {
  name: "myItem",
  value: 'a string'
}

// but now this will throw an exception at runtime:
item.value.version
```

And if you want to treat the value like a `Record` you have to prove it is one first at runtime in order to narrow down the type.

For example:

```
// if it's not a string, it must be the other thing.
if (typeof item.value !== 'string') {
    console.log(item.value.version) // fine
}
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gJ2AeTMAlnAdlAvFAZ2AXSwHMoAfKAJQgGNEATAHiJPIBooAiJiAvR5VeAQ0E8AfAChQkKAElgEALZ4oAbyhZRKiAC5CxUmW4A3UQBsArgdiIUaTDgC+06YyxEo6ZSsNKquoa0lDaunY8KiCBKjycoVAWNnYhYWFmEAgEzoZ8AkKJbm7S6ABmUAAUchBwFb6qAHTJtlAAhLj4AOTsJl0AlJqJYZ4EcJYQjZZwZJUNKs1Wts1ZOdiDAPQbUGWkENIlQA)